# Add sort by relevance to search jobs

Tags: feature-request, tags, jobs, sorting

In Careers 2.0, individuals can choose "search jobs" and sort by `date posted`, `job title`, and `company name`.

However, Careers 2.0 already knows what tags I'm proficient in, and knows the tags associated with the job postings.

A sort option, `relevance`, should be added so that jobs matching my skill set, as demonstrated on stack exchange, will float to the top.

Comment: So to be clear, you want us to match the tags in your profile to the search? Because we already have a sort by relevance options when putting anything in the what search box.

Comment: I think "match[ing] the tags in your profile to the search" is a great idea, also! Though it does need a different descriptor in the `sort by` drop-down.